# Meaning of "bull" in Byron's "this is no bull, although it sounds so"

Tags: meaning, etymology, poetry

From Byron's *[Don Juan](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Don_Juan_(Byron)/Canto_the_Sixth)*:

> One with her flush'd cheek laid on her white arm,
>        And raven ringlets gather'd in dark crowd
>   Above her brow, lay dreaming soft and warm;
>        And smiling through her dream, as through a cloud
>   The moon breaks, half unveil'd each further charm,
>        As, slightly stirring in her snowy shroud,
>   Her beauties seized the unconscious hour of night
>   All bashfully to struggle into light.
>
> This is no **bull**, although it sounds so; for
>        'T was night, but there were lamps, as hath been said.
>   A third's all pallid aspect offer'd more
>        The traits of sleeping sorrow, and betray'd
>   Through the heaved breast the dream of some far shore
>        Belovéd and deplored; while slowly stray'd
>   (As night-dew, on a cypress glittering, tinges
>   The black bough) tear-drops through her eyes' dark fringes.

I immediately thought that this meant **bullshit**, but then I consulted dictionaries and discovered that **bullshit** was coined in the 20th century. Yet it clearly means "false information" here.

If not from **bullshit**, what does it derive from?

Comment: Well, it's usage meaning *bullshit* goes back to the 17th century, apparently. It does seem to be too coarse for a literary work, but then it is Byron.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

*Bull*, without the attending excrement, has meant "exaggerations; lies; nonsense" [since the early seventeenth century](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bull). The excrement emerged in the early twentieth, and since then *bull* has seemed to be a euphemism for *bullshit*, while historically, *bullshit* is actually a dysphemism of *bull*.

Comment: "Medieval Latin **bulla**: play, game, jest" - I never knew that! Quite interesting.

Comment: Given that the 17C was a time of conflict and war between Protestantism and Catholicism with England pretty firmly in the Protestant camp could the use of 'Bull' to mean exaggeration and nonsense be related to the Papal Bulls issued by the supposedly infallible Pope?

Comment: Does this tie up with a _cock and bull story_, as mentioned in _Tristram Shandy_?

Comment: For the records, in Italian we say _bullarsi di qualcuno_ - "to play someone for a fool".

Comment: (the link): n.3 "false talk, fraud," Middle English, apparently from Old French bole "deception, trick, scheming, intrigue," and perhaps connected to modern Icelandic bull "nonsense."    *Sais christ to ypocrites ... yee ar ... all ful with wickednes, tresun and bull.* ["Cursor Mundi," **early 14c.**]

Answer (score 9):

Another peculiar and interesting reference was from [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bull#Middle_English)

with the quote

> From Middle English **bull** (“falsehood”), of unknown origin. Possibly
>   related to Old French *boul, boule, bole* (“fraud, deceit, trickery”).
>   Popularly associated with bullshit.

I am still searching to see if I can offer any corroborating evidence for this early version of **bull**.

It‘s likely this word stood alone in the early Middle English era - that is, it was not a shortened form of *bullshit* at the time.

Also found links to the French *boler* or *bouller* (deceive) from *[Word Origins](https://books.google.it/books?id=hsRISNLSSHAC&pg=PT154&dq=boler%20%22Word%20Origins%22%20by%20John%20Ayto&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvgKf99dTYAhXCJSwKHW56AMMQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=boler%20%22Word%20Origins%22%20by%20John%20Ayto&f=false)* by John Ayto.

> There are three distinct words *bull* in English […] finally there is ‘ludicrous or self-contradictory statement’ usually now in the phrase *Irish bull*, whose origins are mysterious;

The Middle English noun was *bul* (falsehood) and the verb was *bull* (mock, cheat).  However, this is still referring to the 15th - 17th century.

Comment: Boules is also French bowling game... also the English exclamation 'balls!' Or 'that's balls!' also decries something as being untrue nonsense or  'bullshit' - maybe boules is also from 'bulla' - meaning 'play, game, jest' as mentioned above. Boules or lawn bowls (the English version) is also the kind of game where you stand around and chat - so idle talk or 'bullshit' could be present.

Comment: I like your turn of phrase :) Sometimes I think of Cock or Bull as being an animal with alot of bravado but no 'fruit'... That is,... Not wool, no eggs, no milk, no babies but alot of noise and confusion (from the Bulls)

Comment: Of course wool relates to sheep but I think you get the meaning I am projecting

Comment: I see what you mean @Grantly

Answer (score -3):

It could also refer to the ornate decorative symbol on a document:

> A papal bull is a type of public decree, letters patent, or charter issued by a pope of the Roman Catholic Church. It is named after the leaden seal (bulla) that was traditionally appended to the end in order to authenticate it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papal_bull

Comment: It could also refer to the actual animal; but is there any reason to think it *does*?