# You are so full of bull that it boggles the mind

Tags: meaning

> You are so full of bull that it boggles the mind.

Does by any chance this mean, "You are so full of sh*t that it blows my mind"?

If that's not the case, what's the actual meaning of the sentence in the title? (Just to clarify, this is being said during a quarrel.)

Comment: You can find this meaning of "bull" listed in a number of dictionaries. See the [Oxford Dictionaries entry for bull³](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/bull#bull-3). Other questions on this site about the term, ands its relationship to "bullshit"/"bull shit": [Meaning of “bull” in Byron's “this is no bull, although it sounds so”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/425616), [What is the origin of the term “bull****” in its figurative sense?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/460051)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes.**

*Bull* is a shortened euphemism for the word **bullsh*t**.

> Bullshit (also bullcrap) is a common English expletive which may be shortened to the **euphemism *bull.***

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullshit)

And from [The Online Slang Dictionary:](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/bull)

> **3.** nonsense. Euphemism for bullshit.

The meaning of bullsh*t:

> Stupid or untrue talk or writing; nonsense.

From [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bullshit).

Comment: I'd be more inclined to say "Yes and no" as opposed to just "Yes". (In a quote like this, _bull_ could stand for any of its synonyms, really: _balderdash, poppycock, horsefeathers, bullshit, crap, nonsense_, etc.)

Comment: @J.R. How?  I've only ever heard it refer to *bullshit.*  (In the UK, anyway)

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help. What about the "it boggles my mind" part? Did I get it right?

Comment: @Bafforasta Yes.  This part just means 'it is mind-blowing; there is so much bull it is hard to comprehend'.

Comment: Thanks for your help again then.

Comment: @Bafforasta No problem!

Comment: Well, the OP is asking what the word _means_, not "What is it a shortened form of?" (It's just a minor comment, I don't have a problem with the overall gist of your answer. Also, I think my original comment meant to say: "bull could stand *in* for any of its synonyms," but it's too late for me to edit and correct it now.)

Comment: @J.R. Yeah, I see now - nevermind.  You have my permission to edit if you care to

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boggle